# Take two elements in iteration jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, foreach, thymeleaf

I want fill my website with my items from db, and it has to fit to my template - two animals in one line, if there is odd number of animals - the last one is one in the line.

How I should make fillResults function which take two animals from iteration and gives it to addAnimalsMen which fills my template?

```
function findAnimals(gender, catteryStatus, websiteVisibilityStatus) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/admin/api/animals?" + prepareUrl(gender, catteryStatus, websiteVisibilityStatus),
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"
})
.done(function (response) {
    fillResults(response, gender);
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
    displayErrorInformation(jqxhr.responseText);
});
}

function fillResults(response, gender) {
    $("#records_animals_man").empty();
    var animals = response;
    if(gender == 'M'){
        var counter = 0;
        animals.forEach(function(animal){
       counter++;
       if(counter%2 != 0){
            var firstAnimal = animal;
       } else if(counter%2 == 0){
            var secondAnimal = animal;
       }
       addAnimalsMen(firstAnimal, secondAnimal);

        });
    }

}

function addAnimalsMen(firstAnimal, secondAnimal) {
    $('#records_animals_man').append(
        '<div class="rounded bg-light shadow-sm my-5 p-3 text-center">' +
            '<div class="form-row text-center">' +
                '<div class="col-md-2"></div>' +
                prepareAnimalToShow(firstAnimal) +
                prepareAnimalToShow(secondAnimal) +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>'
    );
}


function prepareAnimalToShow(animal){
    return '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 p-4 ml-4 text-center text-secondary border justify-content-center">' +
                                 '<span><strong>' + animal.lineageName + '</strong></span><br><br>' +
                                  prepareImageToShow(animal.image.imageFileName) +
                                 '<br><br><span>' + animal.websiteDescription + '</span><br><br>'+
                     '</div>';
}
```

Comment: The question includes `thymeleaf` as a tag, so when you refer to "_my template_", do you mean a Thymeleaf template? If so, then you cannot populate a Thymeleaf template (which only exists on the server) using JavaScript (which only runs in the browser). The typical approach (again assuming Thymeleaf) is that you pass your data structure to the server-side model. Then, adding data to the template can happen via [Thymeleaf iteration](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#iteration).

Comment: Alternatively, if you want client-side interactions (e.g. with the user making a dynamic selection) then you can use your JavaScript - but it will be altering the DOM (the rendered HTML), not a Thymeleaf template. Maybe you can clarify in the question?